# Who should I call to remove my fireplace?

Tags: fireplace

I'm looking to have my fireplace removed and blocked up in order to use the wall for furniture. I already have 2 vents on the chimney breast upstairs one in each bedroom, I am unsure as to even what forms of trades person carries out this type of work. Any advice and knowledge would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: A mason or bricklayer would be the person who puts a fireplace in, I imagine they could also take one out. The hearth may be bearing a lot of weight from the chimney, so rather than remove it, it may be more sensible / less expensive to just block it off. If you are handy, there are a few guides online for how to DIY it.

Answer (score 1):

Any general contractor could remove the fireplace and if the house uses the brick for suport the contractor will be able to do the needed repairs.